# Cannot authorize user to edit apps-script

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote an apps-script attached to a Google spreadsheet, then transferred the ownership of the spreadsheet to another user. However, the new user cannot edit the apps-script and is not authorized to run it.  I read that Google has upgraded permissions to have apps-scripts inherit the permissions of their parent spreadsheets, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permissions was upgraded, but in an opt-in way. If you open the script and click the "Share" button it will ask you to upgrade to the new permission model.

Comment: I did this earlier, but it had no effect.  Trying again a couple weeks later, it worked.  So maybe there was a glitch server-side that got figured out. Thanks!